# Jquery wont work on specific view Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a problem with Jquery. I'm using Rails 3.2.6, so Jquery is the new defaut.

My problem : I have a scaffolded controller named "sounds", and on my "Show" view, i have a progress bar. I need it to be auto refresh, so some jquery should did the trick.

I included in the "sounds.js.coffee" this simple code =>

```
console.log($("#progressBar"))
```

So, on the url **"/sounds"** (index action), I got this response =
"[]"
 (Its ok), 
and on the url **"/sounds/1/show"** (show action), I got this error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ", so i think Jquery is not
>   recognized.

I can't understand what is the problem.. Is someone already got this prob, thanks to give me some hint and explanations.

**UPDATE**

I found the problem :

This line was at the top of sound.html.erb
`<%= javascript_include_tag :sounds %>` so double inclusion i think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the problem :**

This line was at the top of sound.html.erb
`<%= javascript_include_tag :sounds %>` so double inclusion i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if jquery is included in your application.js file. Also ensure that your application.js file is included in your layout and that your view is using that layout.

Comment: Yes => //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .

Comment: OK and do you have a <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> directive in your application.html file?

Comment: i just found my problem, see the update i make. 
Thanks you for your response, !

Comment: You should answer your own question and put your update in there.